# How to download a filtered CSV file with PHP using Yii 1.1 framework

Tags: php, csv, yii, yii1.x

Before you read any further, I would like to apologize if I am making a duplicate here. I have been looking around for quite a while now and had no luck whatsoever on how to handle the following situation. The entire thing is getting worse because of me being a novice programmer.

**The Situation**

I got a task from my senior programmer at work to create a a function that would generate a CSV file. I had some trouble but finally managed it. The function (located in the model) looks like this.

```
// The function below will return a CSV file.
  public function convert2CSV(){

    $data = $this->search()->rawData;

    $fileOpener = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($fileOpener, array(
       'some code...'
    ), ';');

    foreach ($data as $rows) {
      fputcsv($fileOpener, $rows ';');
    }
    fclose($fileOpener);
}
```

So far so good. Now I got the task to create a filter that will apply to the CSV file as well. What do I mean by this? Well, wenn I use the filter in the website and then export the CSV file it should only download the results of the filter. Up until now, no matter what I did, it simply downloaded everything it could up to its maximum count.

I have tried to get it done by using $_GET to somehow tell the CSV function above to only download the filtered results. I have been trying to do it like this in the controller, within the action that calls the CSV function of the model.

```
 public function actionExport2CSV() {
    $a = new A();
    $b = new B();

  // This part will output the headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
        header('Content-type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TestFile.csv');

  // do not cache the file
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');


        $a->convert2CSV(); {
            if (isset($_GET['B'])) {
                $b->attributes = $_GET['B'];
            }
    }
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help and/or explanation you can give me. I would of course prefer to understand what I am doing wrong, in order to learn more and become a better programmer in the future.

Thanks a lot for your help guys.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind everyone.

I edited the search function in order to filter the CSV file before it is even created.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [EExcelview](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eexcelview) extension, very useful.

1. Download and extract the code in `/protected/extensions/`
2. Add it in your `/protected/config/main.php` file as follow

```php
  'import' => array(
      'app.models.*',
      'app.portlets.*',
      'app.components.*',
      'app.extensions.*',
      ...
      'ext.phpexcel.*', # here we are importing the extension
    ),
```

3. Add and optimize your code in the view where you want to download the CSV file as follow:

```php
 $this->widget('EExcelView', array(
      'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
      'creator'      => Yii::app()->name,
      'grid_mode'    => 'grid',
      'title'        => 'CSV File title',
      'subject'      => 'CSV File Subject',
      'description'  => 'CSV File Description',
      'exportText'   => 'Download file ',
      'filename'     => urlencode('My file to download'),
      'exportType'   => 'CSV', # Available Options => Excel5, Excel2007, PDF, HTML, CSV
      'template'     => "{exportbuttons}",
      'columns'      => array(
          'colA',
          'colB'
          ...
      ),
  ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, mate. I already can download the CSV file. I just need to somehow make it only download the selected results.

Comment: P.S. I will certainly try it with your extension tho, so thanks again.